# get user input value store it to localstorage

Tags: angular, ionic2

I am trying to get user input value, store it as an object and use it later whenever it is required

```
 import { Component } from '@angular/core';    
 import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';

 @Component({
     selector: 'page-login',
     templateUrl: 'login.html'
 })
 export class LoginPage {
     file;
     user = {
         Name: '',
         email: '',
         phone: '',
         Country: ''        
     };
     constructor(public storage: Storage) { }

     writeFile(){    
         var obj = this.user;
         this.storage.set(obj).then(() => {
             this.storage.get(obj).then(() => {
                 console.log(obj.user);
             });
         });
     }
 }
```

And my html is

```
<ion-content  padding>
    <form  #form="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="logForm(form)" novalidate>
        <ion-list inset  position="bottom">
            <ion-item>
                <ion-label>Name</ion-label>
                <ion-input [(ngModel)]="user.Name" name="Name" required type="text"></ion-input>
            </ion-item>

            <ion-item>
                <ion-label >Email</ion-label>
                <ion-input [(ngModel)]="user.email" name="email" required type="Email"></ion-input>
            </ion-item>
             <ion-item>
                <ion-label >Phone Number</ion-label>
                <ion-input [(ngModel)]="user.phone" name="phone" required type="number"></ion-input>
            </ion-item>
             <ion-item>
                <ion-label >Country</ion-label>
                <ion-input [(ngModel)]="user.Country" name="Country" required type="string"></ion-input>
            </ion-item>
        </ion-list>   
            <button ion-button block (click)="writeFile()">write file</button>   
    </form> 
</ion-content>
```

So, when the user enters the values, it will be passed to "user" in listing.ts file. I need to store it to a local storage. I need it see that object in my console.

**EDIT:**
I tried and I got error:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think, when you do `this.storage.set(obj);`, this is a promise. It is not resolved yet when you try to view it at `this.storage.get(obj).then(() => { console.log(obj.user); })`.

Make your code like this:

```
writeFile(){    
    var obj = this.user;
    this.storage.set(key,value).then(() => {
        this.storage.get(obj).then(() => {
            console.log(obj.user);
        });
    });
}
```

This should work. Let me know if it works. :)

**EDIT** : Also, you have to set it in key value format as shown like [this](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/storage/).

I also have a different mechanism by which I do local storage.
It is like this:

```
localStorage.setItem('user',JSON.stringify(jsonObject));
var temp = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
console.log("Temp - ",temp);
```

This also works fine.

Comment: getting err supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target @Sagar Kulkarni

Comment: `storage.set(key,value)` is the syntax. See here - https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/storage/.

Comment: I have edited my answer with another method of doing it. Please check it out. :)