# store prompt input values as object

Tags: angular, ionic2

Hi i have a prompt alert which has a login form, when user enters data to it and on done button click the data entered by the user should be stored as object, and i need to access it and able to see that object to my console

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams, AlertController } from 'ionic-angular';
@Component({
    selector: 'page-login',
    templateUrl: 'login.html'
})

export class LoginPage {
//is this right way to store values from input tag
     xuser = {
                    name: '',
                    email: '',
                    phone: '',
                    country: ''
        }



  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
                    public alertCtrl: AlertController,
    ) { }
    check(){
            console.log("hellow");
            let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
                title: 'User data',
                inputs: [
                    {
                        name: 'name',
                        placeholder: 'Full Name',
                        type: 'text'
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'email',
                        placeholder: 'Email',
                        type: 'email'
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'phone',
                        placeholder: 'phone Number',
                        type: 'number'
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'country',
                        placeholder: 'Country',
                        type: 'text'
                    }
                ],

                buttons: [
                    {
                        text: 'Done',
                        handler: data => {

                           console.log("data given", this.xuser);

                        } 

                    }
                ] 
            });
            alert.present();
        }

//and i need that data to be stored to my local storage and i need to access it
 writeFile(){    
        var obj = this.xuser;
        this.storage.set(obj).then(() => {
            this.storage.get(obj).then(() => {
                console.log(obj.user.name);
            });
        });
```

so when ever user click "check" alert opens with form and i need to store it to local storage, and access it again

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: are you getting errors and where are you calling writeFile?

Comment: i am not able to store user entered values, if i use html page then i will use  ngmodel but in prompt how to get user give values @ Günter Zöchbauer

Comment: What's the difference to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42337285/get-user-input-value-store-it-to-localstorage ?

Comment: you mean access user entered values? and send to your function?

Comment: hmm ya get user input value from prompt and save it to local storage

Comment: added an answer..It should solve it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [here](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/alert/AlertController/).
 You will get the alert input values in data parameter of your handler.

In your `buttons` array,

```
buttons: [{
           text: 'Done',
           handler: data => {
                    this.writeFile(data);//you can access as data.name,data.email etc.
                    console.log("data given", data);
                    } 
          }]
```

You will have to edit your write function to set using data object.

Comment: could i able to access this data outside the prompt function

Comment: you can pass it or set it to a class variable